# VB.NET conditionals with a regex match

Tags: regex, vb.net

I constructed a code that checks if the content in a textbox is a string or an integer.
What i do is the following :

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Public Class Form1

Private Sub btnCheck_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCheck.Click

    Dim value As String = txtBox.Text

    Dim i As Integer
    If (Integer.TryParse(value, i)) = True Then
        If IsValid(value) = True Then
            MsgBox(value & " is a correct entry")
        Else
            MsgBox("Not a correct TVA number !")
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox(value & " is a string")
    End If
End Sub

Function IsValid(ByRef value As String) As Boolean
    Return Regex.IsMatch(value, "^0[1-9]{9}$")
End Function

End Class
```

Now all is working just fine, untill i type in **11 or more numbers** in the textbox, after which the code suddenly tells me that (e.g.) 012345678912 is a string (!)

So to be clear, when i type the following numbers :

- 12345 -> msgbox tells me the entry is "Not a correct TVA number"
- 123456789 -> msgbox tells me the entry is "Not a correct TVA number"
- 0123456789 -> msgbox says it's OK
- 01234567891 -> msgbox tells me the entry is "Not a correct TVA number"
- 012345678912 -> **msgbox tells me the entry is suddenly a string !**
- some text -> msgbox says it's a string so it's OK

Maybe i'm missing something obvious here, but i looked at the code over and over again and i tested the regular expressions a few times in other applications, where they work just fine.

What is it that i'm overlooking here please ?

Regards
Wim

Comment: "^0[1-9]{9,}$" to allow more than 9 digits and Long.TryParse

Comment: Why did you pass `value` argument of `IsValid` function `ByRef` ? It adds no value here or am I missing something ?

Comment: Hi Sehnsucht,

Indeed you're right. I can do it also this way (which leaves out the unnecessary function) :

    Dim i As Int64
    If (Int64.TryParse(value, i)) = True Then

    If Regex.IsMatch(value, "^0[1-9]{9}$") = True Then
                MsgBox(value & " is a correct entry")
            Else
                MsgBox("Not a correct TVA number !")
            End If

        Else
            MsgBox(value & " is a string")
        End If

    End Sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That value is too large for an `Integer`, so it overflows and  `Int32.TryParse` returns `false`.

You could use this:

```
If value.All(AddressOf Char.IsDigit) Then
    If IsValid(value) = True Then
        MsgBox(value & " is a correct entry")
    Else
        MsgBox("Not a correct TVA number !")
    End If
Else
    MsgBox(value & " is a string")
End If
```

or use `Int64.TryParse` instead which allows larger numbers.

Comment: Hi Tim,

Both your suggestions work. I think i read about the int32 and int64 in a past life but completely forgot about that :-D

Indeed i just googled the max number for int32 and it's only 10 digits long. This issue really had me riddled you know ;-)

Thanks !
Wim